# Problemas con archivo de configuración en Webpack

Tags: javascript, configuración, webpack

Estoy probando una plantilla completa `Webpack+React+Redux` para integrar en una página web, pero estoy teniendo este error:

`/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/redux-webpack-es6-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:19

throw new WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors);
Error
at webpack (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/redux-webpack-es6-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:19:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/redux-webpack-es6-boilerplate/dev-server.js:12:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)`

Revisando detenidamente el archivo que da error tenemos lo siguiente:

```
const compiler = webpack(config);
```

Esta línea es la que produce el error en el archivo `dev-server.js`, más específicamente lo hace la variable `config`, que está definida más arriba como:

```
const config = require('./config/webpack.config.development');
```

Por lo cuál deduzco que el problema viene en la configuración.

Sin embargo el `traceback` no da más idea de lo que está mal, con lo cuál no he podido saber que ocurre.

La versión de webpack que estoy usando es `"webpack": "^2.2.1",`. He buscado en internet pero no me ha quedado clara la solución.

[Acá](https://gist.github.com/SalahAdDin/2ab860189844c8a7051697e4c28b46a6) están mis archivos de configuración.

Este es el contenido del archivo configuración para desarrollo:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config.base');
const path = require('path');


const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
  },
  __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'true'))
};

module.exports = merge(config, {
  debug: true,
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    application: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'development'
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'react-router', 'react-router-redux', 'redux']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS)
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Sass
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/styles'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/scripts')
        ],
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css',
          'postcss',
          { loader: 'sass', query: { outputStyle: 'expanded' } }
        ]
      },
      // Sass + CSS Modules
      // {
      //   test: /\.scss$/,
      //   include: /src\/client\/assets\/javascripts/,
      //   loaders: [
      //     'style',
      //     {
      //       loader: 'css',
      //       query: {
      //         modules: true,
      //         importLoaders: 1,
      //         localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
      //       }
      //     },
      //     'postcss',
      //     { loader: 'sass', query: { outputStyle: 'expanded' } }
      //   ]
      // },
      // CSS
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Como resolver este problema?

**Actualización:**

He modificado los dos archivos de configuración y sigo sin obtener un resultado:

*webpack.config.base*

```
// Common Webpack configuration used by webpack.config.development and webpack.config.production

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const bundletracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
const extracttextplugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/client'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/scripts'),
            path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets'),
            path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
            'node_modules'
        ],
        alias: {
            models: path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts/models')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss']
    },
    plugins: [
        // Bundle tracker
        new bundletracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'  // fetch API
        }),
        // Shared code
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'js/vendor.bundle.js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new extracttextplugin("css/application.css")
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                use: extracttextplugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                // JavaScript / ES6
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                // Images
                // Inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8192,
                        name: 'images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                // Fonts
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8192,
                        name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            })
        ];
    }
};
```

*webpack.config.development*

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config.base');
const path = require('path');


const GLOBALS = {
    'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    },
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'true'))
};

module.exports = merge(config, {
    debug: true,
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        application: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            'development'
        ],
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'react-router', 'react-router-redux', 'redux']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS)
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Sass
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            include: [
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/javascripts'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/assets/styles'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/scripts')
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true,
                            outputStyle: 'expanded'
                        }
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                ]
            }

            // Sass + CSS Modules
            // {
            //   test: /\.scss$/,
            //   include: /src\/client\/assets\/javascripts/,
            //   loaders: [
            //     'style',
            //     {
            //       loader: 'css',
            //       query: {
            //         modules: true,
            //         importLoaders: 1,
            //         localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            //       }
            //     },
            //     'postcss',
            //     { loader: 'sass', query: { outputStyle: 'expanded' } }
            //   ]
            // },
            // CSS
        ]
    }
});
```

Cambié todas las lineas de código tal como vi en migración, y en la documentación de algunos `plug-in` que requería, y aún así no funciona.

Que falta por cambiar?

Gracias

Comment: El error está en el archivo de configuración, publica __en tu respuesta__ el contenido de `./config/webpack.config.development`.

Comment: He puesto el enlace del gist donde está la configuración de cada archivo.

Comment: Si, lo vi, por eso te dije editaras tu respuesta para incluirlo.

Comment: Hecho! Pero creo que el error está en la configuración base.

Comment: El problema es que estás usando Webpack 2 como si fuese la versión 1. Webpack 2 intrujo algunos breaking changes respecto a la configuración. Cambia a Webpack 1 y debería funcionar (a mí Webpack 2 me va mal, demora una media de 45s para generar el bundle).

Comment: Puedes explicar como debe quedar entonces la configuración para que funcione correctamente en web pack 2?

Comment: Ha cambiado la forma en como declaras los loaders. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `loaders` ahora se usa `rules`, para cada desde, los loaders van en el array `use` que por cierto deben contener los nombres completos de los loaders. `resolve.root` ya no existe; los plugins de un loader deben estar dentro de `use.loader.options` y debes actualizar los plugins que tienes porque, algunos como `extract-text-plugin` ya no son compatibles. En fin, si quieres migrar toda tu configuración revisa la [guía de migración](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) de Webpack.

Comment: Un momento, que plugins debo actualizar? Todos los que dicen webpack? O absolutamente todos los paquetes? Por que he puesto todos los paquetes en mi proyecto en sus últimas versiones. Por eso he pensando que es mejor usar la última versión de webpack.